# tkinter generate widgets dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need some advice on style and how to generate tk widgets dynamically. I'm downloading some weather data from an API as an xml-string.

What I'm doing is finding certain strings in it for displaying the weather data in a tk frame:

```
def getSingleDate(self, weatherXML, singleDate):
    return weatherXML[weatherXML.index("<"+singleDate+">")+len(singleDate)+2: weatherXML.index("</"+singleDate+">")]


def lookUpData(self, weatherXML):
    weatherDict={}
    weatherData=["localtime", "temp_c", "text", "wind_kph", "wind_dir", "pressure_mb", "precip_mm", "humidity", "cloud", "feelslike_c", "vis_km"]
    for i in range(len(weatherData)):
        weatherDict[weatherData[i]] = self.getSingleDate(weatherXML, weatherData[i])
```

The code works but I wanted to know if there is a more 'pythonic' way to construct the dictionary from my list and the method to generate the actual data from the XML file.

If I wanted to display all my weather data using tkinter: Is there any good way to generate tk labels from the weatherData list or even the weatherDict in pairs (one for the name and one for the value) and how could I possibly change them from any other part of the programme?

Is there a way constructing tk widgets dynamically **and** naming them specifically for calling them later on?

I guess I want to do something like:

```
self.label_temp_c = tk.Label(text=weatherData[0])
self.label_temp_c.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.label_temp_c_value = tkLabel(text=weatherDict['temp_c'])
self.label_temp_c_value.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

But not like that but dynamically. Gots some knots in the brain... need help!

Thanks!

Comment: There are two possible reasons for not hard-coding the widgets.  1. You will separate a weather report into 11 pieces of data that each should go in 1 of 11 widgets.  You don't want to repeat the code above 11 times. 2. You will separate a weather report into an unknown number of pieces with unknown labels, so you want to adjust the widgets to each report.  Which is your reason?  The code will be quite different for each.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way to design my UI. For 11 values I need alone 44 lines of code for setting up the labels. Than I need another 11 lines for filling in the values.